# Slow File Transfer Speeds (~300kB/s) Between Hyper-V Guest and Host/Other Remote Machine in Azure

Tags: networking, azure, redhat, hyper-v, file-transfer

Slow File Transfer Speeds (~300kB/s) Between Hyper-V Guest and Host/Other Remote Machine in Azure

I am seeing extremely slow file transfer speeds between the guest VM and the host VM or directly from the guest VM to another remote VM.

Here are some configuration details:

- The host VM is Windows Data Center 2019
- The Guest VM is RHEL4 using a legacy adapter. This version of rhel has to be used to support the application running on it
- I could not install integration services on this VM, perhaps because it is so old
- Accelerated Networking is enabled
- All disks are SSD with at least Read caching set on them
- There is enough memory and CPU allocated to the hyper-v VM
- The Hyper-v is configured on a internal switch
- rsync is being used with the options "avhW"
- Have attempted hyper-v disk pass through and that did not allow access to the drive
- Splitting the files into smaller chunks has no effect on speed
- The speed between host and another VM in the same network is extremely fast, which leads to the conclusion that the transfer between the guest and the host is the issue
- Many posts online refer to disabling VMQ. This is not available because the legacy adapter is in use.
- All *offloading* settings have been set to disabled on all adapters

The requirement is to transfer large files ~ 1.5TB from the guest VM quickly. Currently using rsync and do not mind an alternative approach to get the files off the guest VM.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, does the NIC on the host (Windows) got QoS ON ? QoS make a big bottleneck, as by default it reserve the OS 80% of the bandwidth for other process task. I suggest to test by removing the QoS.

Comment: @yagmoth555 - running the command " Get-NetAdapterQos -Name "*" " returns nothing. Is this the right command to run?

Comment: I usually do it by the GUI, Iam old school for that

Comment: Doesn't look like QoS is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to extract the files by mounting the Rhel4 vhdx to a centos 8 vm running on hyperv. Once mounted the file transfer speeds were 30x quicker.